# Why can't PHP AWS API find cache folder?

Tags: php, api, caching, amazon-web-services

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'CacheFile_Exception' with message 'The file  
system location '/awscache'; does not exist. Create the directory, or double-
check any relative paths that may have been set.' in /home/content/15/5299015/html/sdk-
1.5.7/lib/cachecore/cachefile.class.php:61
```

I get this response when trying to implement a `dynamodb` feature. This is in my config.inc

```
'default_cache_config' => '/awscache',
```

and /awscache definitely exists.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/awscache` exists at the root of the file system, and has server-writable permissions, right?

Using APC or XCache, however, is overwhelmingly preferred because they're faster, and you don't have to deal with an unreliable file system. :)